# How to use 'getBody()' on a Google document with a standalone script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to do some text/paragraphs replacement in Google Docs that are automatically created by an add-on (autoCrat). I tried this successfully on a bound script but now that I want to try it on a standalone script, I get this error:

> TypeError: Function getBody not found in the DOCUMENT-NAME object.

I don't understand.

Do I need to call a bound script from the standalone script or something like that?

(I hope not.)

The GAS documentation is not helping at all with this, at least with my understanding of what a standalone script is. Maybe it's a trivial error, but all the examples I found here are for bound scripts, which are not what I'm doing (I've already done a bound script and it's working fine).

This very simple code won't work for a standalone script and I don't understand why :

```
function Myfunction() {

    var file = DriveApp.getFileById('doc-id');
    var body = file.getBody();
    Logger.log(body);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because the class returned by getfilebyID is of type File, not Document.
Try something like this:

```
let LogFile = DriveApp.getFileById('doc-id');
let LogDoc = DocumentApp.openById(LogFile.getId());
LogDoc.getBody()
```